# Перевести одномерный массив (N^2) в двумерный (NxN)

Tags: c, массивы

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать код, в котором элементы одномерного массива A(n^2) будут построчно располагаться в матрице B(n,n). Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...Вводим массив...

Для i от 0 до n
    Для j от 0 до n
        целевой_массив[i][j] = начальный_массив[i*n + j]

...
```

Comment: @return, если вы хотите в качестве ответа Виталию предоставить полный код - делайте это отдельным своим ответом (который возможно примут и вы получите рейтинг:). Я не считаю готовый код хорошим решением проблемы, поэтому даю Виталию лишь АЛГОРИТМ. Пожалуйста, не надо **полностью** переписывать мой код. Правка - это улучшение, а не замена чужого ответа своим. Надеюсь на понимание:)

Comment: модераторы тут не причём. У `return` больше 2k репутации поэтому он может делать правки и их никто не будет проверять. Если бы у него было-бы меньше 2k репутации то правку проверяли бы, и вероятнее всего отклонили бы

Comment: Странно. 2000 репутации, на мой взгляд, крайне мало, чтобы вносить непроверяемые правки. Насколько я знаю, я - разумеется - могу ошибаться, для принятия правки, нужно, чтобы ее проверили 2 модератора. Так вот, раз уж создатели сайта хотят что-то дарить на 2000, то можно сделать так, чтобы для принятия правки требовалось подтверждение лишь 1 модератора. Но вообще непроверяемые правки - это, наверное, только тысяч с 10-20. Ну да ладно. Кому вообще важно мое мнение?:) хех

Comment: в основном проверяют не модераторы, а другие участники с репутацией больше чем 2k

Comment: Виталий, если вам помог мой ответ, то примите его, поставив галочку

Comment: А как нам ввести массив? Просто там получается, что ,например, массив А[n*n] и как нам объявить n?

Comment: Объявляем переменную n и вводим ее:), если правильно понял. Не знаю, как это делается в С, но в С++ это int n; cin >> n; Потом с помощью цикла и внутри него вложенного цикла, каждый по n операций вводим массив с помощью строки cin >> array_name[i][j]; где I и j - переменные циклов